# Easy or dummest question. How to add external user to FBA?

Tags: membership-provider

Say I have 10 users (name, email, phone). How do I add them to FBA so they can use sharepoint which is configured to FBA?

I mean do I need to go to SQL box and add each member. (I know from site permission you can add users but I am not if the users should be present in the sql member database before I do this).

Comment: can anyone help me on this please? by the way I can't download the codeplex tool for fba. guys please let me know what are my options.

Answer (score 1):

Have them register as users via FBA, log into the site, get the 403 message and request access, then you as the admin can set their permission levels